# httpd error after install for Openldap

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, openldap

I have made all the settings for openldap, less then httpd.
After I installed httpd, when I tried to start it with "serice httpd start",
display the following error:

```
[root@elara pub]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I understood from net, that i need to kill a process, but I'm very confused, because I'm nubbie in Linux.
Can' someone tell me a solution for my problem?

Comment: you already have something bound to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you installed OpenLDAP incorrectly to listen at port 80. The correct port for LDAP is 389; 636 for LDAPS.